# What is the biggest SD memory card a Nintendo Wii can support?

Tags: nintendo-wii

OK I read that the Wii can support SD cards up to 2 GB then I read of an update that removed this limitation.

What is the actual maximum SD card size the Wii can support if I keep it updated with official updates from Nintendo? Also is there a limitation on the SD card type (SD, SDHC...)?

Comment: The "wii" doesn't deal with the SD card at all. the Software running on the Wii supports the SD card. Older games run older software. newer games newer software. http://www.wiibrew.org/wiki/SD/SDHC_Card_Compatibility_Tests

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The other thing to bear in mind is that some (older) games won't recognise larger cards so you may end up having to buy several cards anyway.

We have a 8GB card that the kids store Wii channels on that works just fine, but Guitar Hero won't recognise it so we have to use a 2GB to store the GH downloadable content (extra songs etc.)

Comment: I didn't know this, good bit of information to have.

Comment: Rock Band 2 has the same issue.  It cannot use anything bigger than 4GB.

Comment: This explains things. :-) How many Guitar Hero songs is that?

Comment: @Roger - I'll have to ask @Ronan

Comment: Has any on got info on the 256MB memory Card for the Wii?

Answer (score 22):

With Wii Menu 4.0 and above you can use up to 32gb SDHC cards. Full details can be found on [Nintendo's customer support site](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2516/~/what-sd-cards-are-compatible?).

You can use SD, SDHC and miniSD or microSD with adapters.

Answer (score 2):

I think the important thing to note here is that the wii seems to prefer Fat and Fat32. Fat32 maxes out at 32gb, so anything larger than that is going to probably get stuck in NTFS or exFat and the Wii isn't going to know what to do with that. If you had something larger than 32gb, you could partition it, but most likely you'll only be able to read the first partition, which can only be a maximum of 32gb. So.. 32gb, that is basically the max.

Comment: Actually, the limit for fat32 is considerably larger than 32gb, but windows will not natively format fat32 to partitions larger than 32gb - but a specialized program like [Ridgecrop's FAT 32 Formatter](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm) can do it quite handily (and they have a gui version). Most, if not all, devices that support SDHC will support larger capacity SDXC cards (64gb+) that have been re-formatted in this way. See also my answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133045/what-are-the-specs-for-the-highest-end-sd-card-the-3ds-can-support/133058#133058).

Answer (score -3):

I have 3 wiis all with 128 Gb sd cards all formatted as fat 32. Also all have 1Tb harddrives plugged in also formatted as fat 32.  Google fat formater you'll find the program the raspberry pi people use this program to format large sd cards and drives to fat 32.  I have not had any issues running any of my games threw this set up have 500 plus game cube games and 60 wii games on hard drive. on the sd card have every NES, SNES, N64, GameBoy, GameBoy Color, GameBoy Advance, Sega Game Gear, Sega Genesis, Sega Master System, Sega Cd.
My point here is 128 Gb sd card formatted as fat 32 works fine

Comment: While this is helpful information it doesn't seem to answer the question. They want to know what the biggest memory card they can use is while you're telling them what works for you.